# Error when trying to configure Contact detail custom page navigation on community

Tags: community, customer-community, experience-cloud

Getting the below error while trying to navigate to contact detail object page in community

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do this currently. The solution is to make a custom Lightning component.

Upvote the idea here and maybe it will be possible in the future: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdjr6UAB/allow-dynamic-urls-for-standard-community-pages